# Why this error: Undefined property: Twig_Environment in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am getting this error: `Notice: Undefined property: Twig_Environment::$render in` when trying to send a message from a `PHP`-file to a `twig`-file when is wrong login. I want to show the same page with the message from mu `PHP`-file like that:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render('register.twig');

if (isset($_POST['reg'])) {

    if ($_POST['pwd1'] === $_POST['pwd2']) {

    } else {
        echo ("<script>location.href = $twig->render('register.twig', array('theMessage' => 'Wrong password!'));</script>");
        exit;
    }
}
```

and in `twig`-file:

```
{% if theMessage %}
  {{ theMessage }}
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work and I get the error above. I am having big trouble to try to resolve it. I am open to any suggestions or hint.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PHP is interpolating the `$twig` variable inside your message. It's better to change this code:

```
echo ("<script>location.href = $twig->render('register.twig', array('theMessage' => 'Wrong password!'));</script>");
```

To this one:

```
echo sprintf("<script>location.href = %s;</script>", $twig->render('register.twig', array('theMessage' => 'Wrong password!')));
```

Comment: `@Javier Eguiluz` Now I am getting the same side double with your solution. Because there are 2 `echo`, one bfore `if` and yours. But I want to redirect the side to the last `echo` when is wrong password with the message.

Comment: `@Javier Eguiluz` I forgot to say that with your solution worked, but the page is modified. It seems that the `render` method is not called?!

Comment: `location.href` will make the URL of the browser change immediately to the given URL. In my opinion you should change your original example because that's probably not what you want to do.